# Drawing the alpha channel correctly in OpenGl

Tags: c++, opengl, alpha

After loading an image, I have the individual bytes for each channel loaded into an array of unsigned characters. It's passed to a function that projects it as a texture onto a quad. Everything seems to work properly other than the alpha channel, which shows up as the background color. I'm using OpenGL to draw the image. Would I benefit by adding a layering mechanism? Also, how can I achieve the transparent effect that I want?

Note: This is the code that I have a feeling needs changed:

```
void SetUpView()
{
    // Set color and depth clear value
    glClearDepth(1.f);
    glClearColor(1.f, 0.f, 0.f, 0.f);

    // Enable Z-buffer read and write
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glDepthMask(GL_TRUE);

    glEnable (GL_BLEND); 
    glBlendFunc (GL_ONE, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

    // Setup a perspective projection
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective(90.f, 1.f, 1.f, 500.f);
};
```

Also, here's the code to render the quad.

```
void DrawTexturedRect(RectBounds *Verts, Image *Texture)
{
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GetTextureID(Texture));

    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
    glPixelZoom(1, -1);

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glTexCoord2f(0.0, 1.0);
    glVertex3f(Verts->corners[0].x, Verts->corners[0].y, Verts->corners[0].z);

    glTexCoord2f(1.0, 1.0);
    glVertex3f(Verts->corners[1].x, Verts->corners[1].y, Verts->corners[1].z);

    glTexCoord2f(1.0, 0.0);
    glVertex3f(Verts->corners[2].x, Verts->corners[2].y, Verts->corners[2].z);

    glTexCoord2f(0.0, 0.0);
    glVertex3f(Verts->corners[3].x, Verts->corners[3].y, Verts->corners[3].z);
    glEnd();
};
```

The Image class holds an array of unsigned chars, obtained using OpenIL.

Relevant code:

```
loaded = ilLoadImage(filename.c_str());
ilConvertImage(IL_RGBA, IL_UNSIGNED_BYTE);

unsigned char *bytes = ilGetData();

//NewImage is an instance of an Image. This is returned and passed to the above function.
NewImage->data = bytes;
```

[image: Problem]

Comment: Not enough data. You didn't show texture loading routine, and you didn't show actual rendering routine.

Comment: Okay, I tried clearing up what's happening in the render loop.

Comment: Also, how do you setup OpenGL? Are you sure you are requesting alpha channel at all (e.g. pixel format if using glut, GLUT_RGBA if using glut)?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you're talking about, but this happens when the texture is first loaded.
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, Texture->GetWidth(), 
    Texture->GetHeight(), 0, GL_RGBA, 
    GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, Texture->data);

Answer (score 2):

Before drawing anything transparent you should call:

```
glDepthMask(false);
```

And then afterwards:

```
glDepthMask(true);
```

Also, all transparent objects must be drawn after all opaque ones.

Answer (score 0):

glClearColor(1.f, 0.f, 0.f, 0.f);

I'd assume that's at the RGBA default, and you're setting red to 1.0.

How about a better explanation of what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: See the red box around the cursor? In Paint.Net, there's nothing there. It's supposed to be the alpha channel.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
glBlendFunc (GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

Edit: I know what that looks like.  It looks like you are drawing the blue square (Which has a Z-order position placing it behind the cursor) AFTER the cursor.  You have to draw things in the correct, back-to-front Z-Order when alpha blending or you see errors like you are seeing.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm still getting the same effect. Should that be called once, or every frame?